# Apply blur to img tag outside svg tag in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, svg, internet-explorer-10, svg-filters

IE10 giving issues with svg image blur.

```
<svg id="blurjs-10">
   <filter id="blur10px">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" in="SourceGraphic">
   </filter>
</svg>
<img class="blurjs-10-radius" src="863e.png">
```

where blurjs-10-radius is,

```
.blurjs-10-radius{
   filter: url("#blur10px");
}
```

This works fine in firefox, chrome, safari etc. However, this fails in IE10 because it expects `<img>` tag to be inside `<svg>` tags. I cannot have that in my application. Any solutions?

Comment: You've successfully painted yourself into a corner with your not in an <svg> tag restriction.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well I have a fullscreen background that I need to blur, so yea it can't be inside svg. But it really sucks that IE10 is the ONLY browser that doesn't support these codes.

Comment: I don't see why the fullscreen background stops you. Perhaps you should tell us your actual problem with that use case rather than adding restrictions that may or may not be true.

Comment: @RobertLongson the issue is that I have a function that appends `<img class="with fullscreen properties (also on window resize)">` inside `<body>` tags. After this another function appends blur codes (from my question) to the `<body>` tag and adds `blurjs-10-radius` class to the fullscreen image. If I put this image inside `svg` tags it's fullscreen properties will not work. So I want to make IE10 behave like other browsers and implement blur on image outside svg tags.